# How to use maxlength for decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My database table column length is (13,3), 
I'm using HTML maxlength for normal text and number text boxes.
But i cannot use that for decimal number validation, is there any way i can use maxlength property of HTML to validate this?.

Comment: use maxlength = 14 with a regex to validate the pattern

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @sivaprakash see my updated answer for an example. Hope it helps. ; )

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTML text input [`pattern`](https://html.com/attributes/input-pattern/) attribute.

For example :

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="0.000" maxlength="14" pattern="\d{1,10}(?:\.\d{1,3})?$" />
```

This pattern will validate these :

- 1
- 1.001
- 1234567890
- 1234567890.123

And will through error for these :

- 1.
- 1.1234
- 12345678901
- .123

Comment: yeah that's what I was talking about